# Integrating AngularJS with Symfony2 form

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, forms, symfony

I am working on a symfony2 form, wherein I have two drop-downs. Now I need the following functionality - "Based on the selected value of the first dropdown, the second drop-down gets populated". I was able to do this by using simple if/else conditions in jquery. Here is the jquery code

```
function loadProgram(program) {
    if (program === 'msc') {
        var element = document.getElementById("candidate_programofinterest");
        var programSelected = element.options[element.selectedIndex].text;
        removeAllOptions(document.candidate.candidate_programofinterest);
        addOption(document.candidate.candidate_programofinterest, '0', 'Masters - Information Systems Management');
        addOption(document.candidate.candidate_programofinterest, '1', 'Masters - Software Engineering');
        addOption(document.candidate.candidate_programofinterest, '2', 'Masters - Computer Security');
        loadIntake('masters');
    } else if (program === 'me') {
        var element = document.getElementById("candidate_programofinterest");
        var programSelected = element.options[element.selectedIndex].text;
        removeAllOptions(document.candidate.candidate_programofinterest);
        addOption(document.candidate.candidate_programofinterest, '8', 'ME - Global IT Management');
        addOption(document.candidate.candidate_programofinterest, '9', 'ME -  Software Development and Multimedia');
        addOption(document.candidate.candidate_programofinterest, '10', 'ME - Systems, Networks and Security');
        loadIntake('me');
    } else {
        var element = document.getElementById("candidate_programofinterest");
        var programSelected = element.options[element.selectedIndex].text;
        removeAllOptions(document.candidate.candidate_programofinterest);
        addOption(document.candidate.candidate_programofinterest, '', 'Choose a Program');
        addOption(document.candidate.candidate_programofinterest, '3', 'Bachelors of Computer Science');
        addOption(document.candidate.candidate_programofinterest, '4', 'Exchange Program');
        addOption(document.candidate.candidate_programofinterest, '5', 'Study Abroad');
        addOption(document.candidate.candidate_programofinterest, '6', 'Scientific Summer School');
        addOption(document.candidate.candidate_programofinterest, '7', 'French Summer School');
    }
}
```

Note: If I turn the javascript off from the browser, the fields will be displayed properly, except that the second drop-down won't display filtered options based on value selected in the first drop-down, instead all the options would be displayed on page-load itself.

After this I tried to create the drop-downs again inside the symfony2 form itself, but this time using AngularJS. Here is the HTML(twig) code:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<select ng-model="selectedTypeName" ng-options="item.type as item.text for item in type_names">
<option value="">Choose Program Type</option>
</select>

<select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="item.id as item.text for item in names|filter:{type:selectedTypeName}">
<option value="">Choose a Program</option>
</select>

</div>
```

Here is the AngularJS code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.type_names = [
        {id: '0', type: 'me', text: 'Master of Computer Engineering'},
        {id: '1', type: 'msc', text: 'Master of Computer Science'},
        {id: '2', type: 'others', text: 'Others'}
    ];
    $scope.names = [
        {id: '0', type: 'msc', text: 'Masters - Information Systems Management'},
        {id: '1', type: 'msc', text: 'Masters - Software Engineering'},
        {id: '2', type: 'msc', text: 'Masters - Computer Security'},
        {id: '3', type: 'others', text: 'Bachelors of Computer Science'},
        {id: '4', type: 'others', text: 'Exchange Program'},
        {id: '5', type: 'others', text: 'Study Abroad'},
        {id: '6', type: 'others', text: 'Scientific Summer School'},
        {id: '7', type: 'others', text: 'French Summer School'},
        {id: '8', type: 'me', text: 'ME - Global IT Management'},
        {id: '9', type: 'me', text: 'ME -  Software Development and Multimedia'},
        {id: '10', type: 'me', text: 'ME - Systems, Networks and Security'}
    ];

});
```

In the above AngularJS approach I have populated both drop-downs using javascript, opposite to the previous approach where I used PHP to populate the drop-downs.

Note: In this approach, If I turn javascript off from the browser my drop-downs won't get populated.

My problem is, I need Symfony(PHP) to display my form and populate the drop-down options, but I need AngularJS to filter the second drop-down options based on the value selected in the first drop-down, like I did with jquery. All this and keeping scalability in mind.

Also I want Angular to do front-end validation for me. But I guess that is step two.

Note: For robustness I am using server validation as well as front end.

Comment: ajax is your friend

Comment: what changes do I need to make in existing HTML(twig), so I can fetch the elements and manipulate their values, like I do in jquery eg. `document.getElementById("#someId")`